# Fetch language list of sitecore items

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have items created in various languages in sitecore.
I need to fetch the list of languages in which that item is created.
Example:
If available languages in sitecore  are : en,de,fr,it,en-GB.
But the item is created in only en and de, i need to have list of languages as en and de.
can someone provide me the piece of code for obtaining that.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Item` class has a property called `Languages` which returns list of languages that the item has content in.

```cs
Sitecore.Globalization.Language[] langs = item.Languages;
```

and if you need just string list with names of the languages you can use:

```cs
List<string> langNames = item.Languages.Select(l => l.Name).ToList();
```